# SwiftyJson get value of json from complicated structure of JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

This my json.file:

```
[
{
"date_range": "2016-11-01-2016-12-31",
"order_status_id": 3,
"jobs": [
  {
    "date": "2016-11-14",
    "job": [
      {
        "id": 143608,
        "pickup_worker_id": null,
        "drop_off_worker_id": 57
      }
           ]
   }
       ]
 }

 {
    "date_range": "2016-11-01-2016-12-31",
    "order_status_id": 2,
    "jobs": [
       {
          "date": "2016-11-16",
          "job": [
             {
                "id": 143238,
                "pickup_worker_id": null,
                "drop_off_worker_id": 12
              }, 
            {
                "id": 13218,
                "pickup_worker_id": null,
                "drop_off_worker_id": 42
              } 
                 ]
       },
       {
          "date": "2016-11-19",
          "job": [
             {
                "id": 141238,
                "pickup_worker_id": null,
                "drop_off_worker_id": 12
              } 

                 ]
           }


             ]
   }
]
```

---

This my code for `swiftyjson`:

```
 Alamofire.request(Constants.web_api+api_get_orders, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: Constants.headers ).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            print("All Data JSON \(swiftyJsonVar)")

          print("date range1\(swiftyJsonVar["date_range"])")
          print("date range2\(swiftyJsonVar["date_range"].stringValue)")
            print("jobs1 \(swiftyJsonVar["jobs"].arrayObject)")
            print("jobs2 \(swiftyJsonVar["jobs"].array)")
            print("jobs3 \(swiftyJsonVar["jobs"])")
            print("jobs date \(swiftyJsonVar["jobs"]["date"].stringValue)")
            print("jobs date \(swiftyJsonVar["jobs"]["job"]["drop_off_worker_id"].stringValue)")

        }
```

The output , all is null or nil except All Data JSON (`swiftyJsonVar`). How can I get value of `date_range`, `drop_off_worker_id` ? I really hope someone can help me. I spend a lot of time for solve it but still can't solve it.

Comment: Why not use ObjectMapper for more structured/modular programming?

Comment: ObjectMapper ? can u give me the link about that ?

Comment: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Comment: Thanks .. i need study the documentation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON response is `Array` not `Dictionary`, so you need to access its first object to get the detail you want.

```
if let dateRange = swiftyJsonVar[0]["date_range"].string  {
    print(dateRange)
}
if let worker_id = swiftyJsonVar[0]["jobs"][0]["job"][0]["drop_off_worker_id"].int {
    print(worker_id)
}
```

**Edit:** If you have multiple object in your root than get all the `dateRange` and `worker_id` in for loop.

```
for subJson in swiftyJsonVar.array {

    if let dateRange = subJson["date_range"].string  {
         print(dateRange)
    }
    for jobsJson in subJson["jobs"].array {
         for jobJson in jobsJson["job"].array {
              if let worker_id = jobJson["drop_off_worker_id"].int {
                   print(worker_id) 
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank i got dateRange .. but if i have many of array ..You see, i updated my question.. how can i get all of drop_off_worker_id ?

Comment: @A.Shukri -  `for-loop`? Use that to iterate over your data.

Comment: yes i know for-loop .. but how can i get size or length for jobs or dateRange ?

Comment: @A.Shukri Don't get you have you try edited answer with for loop, it is batter if you show us your whole response.

Comment: my response very long but it same structure ... u look first array .. daterange, order_status_id and job (child) .. it same but i just show two .. actually it have many

Comment: @A.Shukri Is `jobs` array and `job` array always contains single object or they too contains multiple objects?

Comment: @NiravD .. I updated my json file .. in jobs it can be multiple , sometime maybe just one or empty .. in job also can be multiple or just one ..

Comment: I run your code , it have error at swiftyJsonVar.arrayValue .. It said ..  'JSON' is not convertible to '(String, JSON)'

Comment: hey @A.Shukri Accept answer now so it helps others too if you doesn't know how to accept answer check this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/346600

Answer (score 0):

Please try, by referring the index of the element in the array.

```
Alamofire.request(Constants.web_api+api_get_orders, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: Constants.headers)
  .responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
  if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
    print("All Data JSON \(swiftyJsonVar)")

    print("date range1\(swiftyJsonVar[0]["date_range"])")
    print("date range2\(swiftyJsonVar[0]["date_range"].stringValue)")
    print("jobs1 \(swiftyJsonVar[0]["jobs"].arrayObject)")
    print("jobs2 \(swiftyJsonVar[0]["jobs"].array)")
    print("jobs3 \(swiftyJsonVar[0]["jobs"])")
    print("jobs date \(swiftyJsonVar[0]["jobs"]["date"].stringValue)")
    print("jobs date \(swiftyJsonVar[0]["jobs"]["job"]["drop_off_worker_id"].stringValue)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. how can i get length or size or jobs ? if look at my json , have two jobs ...

Comment: `for(_,job):(String, JSON) in swiftyJsonVar {
        //job is available here as a Dictionary
      }`